# Hero Lab : What are the +nn/+nn/+nn for?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, tools, hero-lab

Posted here is a screenshot of my eidolon, but the numbers are all over the place on other characters.  I'm not sure what terminology to use to describe it is because I have no idea of the purpose.  Is this a stat for additional attacks/rd. or just the bonuses you use for hasted attacks after the first full attack?  I apologise for my ignorance in advance but I'm curious about this.

[image: melee-screenshot]

Comment: Welcome to RPG Stackexchange!  Please take a look at the [About] (it's a sort of tour) when you get a chance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Those are the attack bonuses for iterative attacks in a full attack action for this creature with that weapon.  This creature gets three attacks in a full attack, at +20, +20, and +15, each of which deal out `3d6+27+1d6` acid damage. It includes whatever buffs you have activated in Hero Lab - so if you have Haste on in the Adjust tab, then there's an extra attack for Haste in that line - or not, if not.

Here's the witch I was playing today's weapon tab, showing the normal 2 attacks for a BAB above +5:

[image: Witch Weapons]

And then again with Haste applied:

[image: Witch Weapons With Haste]

This is just like in a creature's stat block.  In fact, you could output the stat block of this creature in Hero Lab if you're unclear how things are mapping to each other (File... Output Hero Statblock...).

```
Sredni Vashtar's Girl
Female Human (Vudrani) Witch 12
NG Medium humanoid (human)
Init +9; Senses Perception +7
**Defense**
AC 24, touch 15, flat-footed 21 (+4 armor, +4 shield, +3 Dex, +1 natural, +2 deflection)
hp 108 (12d6+51)
Fort +11, Ref +13, Will +14
**Offense**
Speed 30 ft.
Melee +1 mithral dagger +8/+3 (1d4+2/19-20)
...
```

Comment: So that means I can swing that hammer three times during a full attack action.  Thank you for the swift answer!